# Link columns so data updates are properly reflected

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, array-formulas

I have a column with data values and I want to link it to other columns in the same and different sheets but in the same spreadsheet. This is, having the same data in different columns in a spreadsheet while keeping all linked so updates on the source one would affect all of them.

I've tried with:

```
=SheetName!ColumnIndex:ColumnIndex
```

(e.g. `=Sheet1!A:A`) but, although it works, it is a cell reference not a column reference.

What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: What is the ideal function you expect? A column number to be used?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe what you want is just the array version of what you have already tried:

```
=arrayformula(Sheet1!A:A)
```

(If not, please clarify!)

Comment: Is there a way to rearrange the columns while using this?